# Can someone who held H4 visa previously visit USA on B2 visitor visa

Tags: usa, h4-visa

Can someone who held H4 visa previously visit USA again on B2 visitor visa.

- Came to USA on a H4 visa in 2015
- Went back to India in 2016
- H4 visa has expired.
- Awaiting a divorce so applying for a H4 visa again is not an option.
  Can B2 visa be filed to visit USA for 2 months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can always apply for a B2 visa if your purpose is to visit the US. But there is no guarantee you will get it.

Comment: Could the B2 visa be rejected on the basis of holding a prior H4 visa?

Comment: @CodingDawg not per se, no.  That is, they will not reject you simply because you held the H-4.  They can reject you for all sorts of other reasons, though, some of which could conceivably be related to your H-4.  They may also reject you independently of the H-4 depending on the reasons you give for wanting to travel to the US and the credibility of your application.  For example, if you apply for a B-2 visa for a stated purpose that is not allowed for B-2 visitors, your visa will be refused.  This will also happen if you claim an allowed purpose but your application causes them to doubt you.